# Xamarin.forms Pinch and Zoom

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to have a control which allows me to pinch and zoom using **ONLY** Xamarin.Forms controls.

I want to display an image in any control from xamarin.forms(WebView or Image or any other ) and be able to zoom from the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using meta viewport for zooming as follows.
This might not be a solution for every one but it worked for me.

Put the image hex -64 inside the image tag below and then put the whole html in WebView.

```
this.WebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource { BaseUrl = URL, Html = html };

The html will be defined here.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=3.0 user-scalable=1">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0 20px 0 0;
            font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, HelveticaNeue-UltraLight, Helvetica, Consolas, 'Courier New';
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px outset;
            border-color: #3c4142;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,YourBase64imagestringhere" style="width:100%" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want something like this , but i cant understand this src="data:image/png;base64,YourBase64imagestringhere" , how can i add my static image here ?? My image path is "myproject.Images.test.jpg"

Comment: First you need to change the image to base 64 string  see the link below on how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-image-path-to-base64-string. Then you inject the base 64 result(Which is very big string) and place it in the placeholder which is YourBase64imagestringhere in my code. you have to have a way of passing data to an html. In my case I am using Razor views from nancy fx.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to pinch/zoom with pure built-in Forms controls as of the time of this post. There is a way to achieve this but you have to implement a native renderer for that.

I achieved this in an app I'm writing by creating a class that inherits from Xamarin.Forms.ContentView - PanGestureContainer, which has properties such as number of touch points min/max  and an event to listen to.

In the iOS project I made a custom renderer for my view, where the renderer takes the properties from the view and hooks up touch event listeners.

Additionally I made an attachable property (aka Behavior) that can be applied to other Views and when applied it takes the view from its parent, wraps it inside a PanGestureRecognizer and another attached property acts as an event listener wrapper the same way.

It's a complete hack but covers the missing functionality until Xamarin implements it cleanly

---

Update: now with sample code, **seriously trimmed down** as it would be too much to post, it should give you an idea how to achieve this rather that be a copy/paste solution. If it seems like too much it probably is, I'm sure there are better ways but it does the trick until this functionality is baked-in.

```
  public abstract class BaseInteractiveGestureRecognizer : BindableObject, IInteractiveGestureRecognizer
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<BaseInteractiveGestureRecognizer, ICommand> ((b) => b.Command, null, BindingMode.OneWay, null, null, null, null);

        public ICommand Command {
            get {
                return (ICommand)base.GetValue (BaseInteractiveGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty);
            }
            set {
                base.SetValue (BaseInteractiveGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public object CommandParameter {get;set;} // make bindable as above

        public GestureState State { get;set;} // make bindable as above

        public View SourceView{ get; set; } 

        public void Send ()
        { 
            if (Command != null && Command.CanExecute (this)) {
                Command.Execute (this);
            }
        }
    }

public class PanGesture : BaseInteractiveGestureRecognizer
{
    public uint MinTouches { get;set; } // make bindable
    public uint MaxTouches { get;set; } // make bindable
    // add whatever other properties you need here - starting point, end point, touch count, current touch points etc.
}
```

And then in the iOS project:

```
public abstract class BaseInteractiveGestureRenderer : BindableObject,IGestureCreator<UIView>
    {
        public abstract object Create (IInteractiveGestureRecognizer gesture, Element formsView, UIView nativeView);

        public static GestureState FromUIGestureState (UIGestureRecognizerState state)
        {
            switch (state) {
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Possible:
                return GestureState.Possible;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                return GestureState.Began;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                return GestureState.Update;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
                return GestureState.Ended;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled:
                return GestureState.Cancelled;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Failed:
                return GestureState.Failed; 
            default:
                return GestureState.Failed;
            }    
        }
    }


using StatementsHere;
[assembly: ExportGesture (typeof(PanGesture), typeof(PanGestureRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespaceHere.iOS
{
public class PanGestureRenderer : BaseInteractiveGestureRenderer
{
    public PanGestureRenderer () : base ()
    {   
    }

    #region IGestureCreator implementation

    public override object Create (IInteractiveGestureRecognizer gesture, Element formsView, UIView nativeView)
    {   
        PanGesture panGesture = gesture as PanGesture; 
        nativeView.UserInteractionEnabled = true; 

        UIPanGestureRecognizer panGestureRecognizer = null;
        panGestureRecognizer = new UIPanGestureRecognizer (() => panGesture.Send());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sten Petrov Your answer could be helpful but I must use only Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @Amete this *is* Xamarin.Forms, renderers are a part of it

Answer (score 0):

Use Mr.Gestures package from Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/MR.Gestures/