# how to convert image into string in c#? Especially in Monotouch ios

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.ios

I am new to c#. I am developing an iOS project. i want to upload images to server. So i want to convert image into string. can anyone help me to do this.

I am agree any type of method to upload image to sever.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-image-path-to-base64-string

Comment: @aberna, i want to upload images to php from my iOS app. thats main issue.

Answer (score 3):

How about that?

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader binreader = new BinaryReader(stream);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) stream.Length];
buffer = binreader.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);
string serialized = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
```

If you have the System.Drawing.Image object instead of a file path, you can do:

```
System.Drawing.Image image; //initialize it someway
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); //if it is jpeg
byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();
string serialized = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

And then you pass the 'serialiazed' value to the server.

Put if it will work depends on how the server will handle that.

Comment: i got somethng  can't able to read by human. okay. how to send that to php server?

Comment: hello heringer, say me, which one i have to pass to server? and you have converted imagefilepath instead image? no need to convert image?please explain. i can't understand.

Comment: i got two error when i am trying with your second method. Error is i cant use System.Drawing.ImageView.Image.i mean, i have image on imageview. how o set it to system.drawing? second error is Save does not ahve any definiton. how to solve this? guide me heringer.

Answer (score 2):

The same just a little bit less code

```
//Clientside    
byte[] imgBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("FilePath");
string imgStr = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);

//Serverside 
byte[] serverSideImgBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(imgStr);
File.WriteAllBytes("PathAndFileName", serverSideImgBytes);
```

Comment: server is php.. how can apply this codes to php?

Comment: i think you can use php function named base64_decode

Comment: guys, you all teach me how to convert filepath. i don't need to convert filepath. i need to convert image only. not its path. please understand.

Comment: Replace FilePath on the path to your image like ../Images/Picture.jpg.  And when you will send image bytes to server send filename for saving.