# C# Xamarin equavalant of System.Drawing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, byte

I am trying to find the equivalent of System.Drawing for Android.

As I found [Converting UIImage to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112314/converting-uiimage-to-byte-array) but this seems to be only being used for iOS and within the xamarin docs is not much usefull to find http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=root%3a%2fmono-libs

The only thing I try to accomplish is to convert an image to an byte[]

I know ho to use this:

```
using (Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
                bytes = (Byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(Byte[]));
                height = image.Height;
                width = image.Width;
                size = image.Size;
            }
```

Also a possibillity for me is to get the image and being able to post it in an submit form to WS. In other words if I am able the get the whole image and post this I would be also happy.
IF something is unclear let me know.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497340/how-to-convert-image-into-string-in-c-especially-in-monotouch-ios

Comment: its for iOS only....

Comment: I can't see any iOS specific code there...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Android.Graphics namespace.