# I want to save image in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image on a page, e.g `<img id="img3" runat="server" src="image.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>` and I'd like to save the image referenced by the `src` attribute in my database using stored procedure.

I should convert the image to binary first.
Here is what I have so far:

```
    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", byte);
```

But the thing is that I don't want to save the uploaded image `FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream`, I want to save the image that I had its `src`.

Is there a way to put the image `src` in stream so that I can save it or what is the right way for doing that?

Comment: Are you saying the filename of the image becomes FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream once it's deserialized from the database?

Comment: BTW! Its not recommended to save images into database, use folder instead.

Comment: whay do you meand by src? you get it from  a web page ?

Comment: i have an image on my web page i want to save it in database but the problem is that "Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;" saves the uploaded image not the one that i want 
for ex: i have <img id="img3" runat="server" src="image.jpg" width="200" height="200"/> i want to save this image to database not the uploaded one

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is not recommended to store images in Database or any other type of files in RDBMS. What is most effective way, to store the file over disk on server, and store that path in your table.

So whenever you need to reference that image/file, then fetch the path from the database, and read the file from disk. This broadly has following two benefits.

1. Removes the extensive conversion process (from image to binary and
   vice-versa).
2. Helps to read the image directly (soft-read).

Answer (score 1):

Saving an image in the database is not recommanded, but if you insist on saving it in your database you can convert the image to base64, then save the base64 string in your database.

```
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
{                 
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        //Now save the base64String in your database
    }                  
}
```

And to convert it back from base64 to an image:

```
public Image GetImageFromBase64String(string base64String)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    Image image;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    return image;
```

I combined some code from [converting a base 64 string to an image and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it)
and from [Convert image path to base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-image-path-to-base64-string) .

Comment: This shouldn't happen at very first place. If you are dealing with good amount of files, then this way will be more process extensive at both, code level as well as at DB level.

Comment: Im just giving him what he asked for, whether its good or not is up to him to decide.

Comment: `Base64String` takes more memory than image actual size.

Comment: Yes by seeing your answer, I can see that. But at the same time, it is our duty to redirect user for the right approach, not for what is asked unless restricted by the business requirement. However in this case, he can simply deal with file-system instead of Database. Rest up to you sir.

Comment: ok thanks a lot guys :) im a new developer and i don't have a good experience yet thanks for helping

Comment: @AmneshGoel youre absolutly right, ill edit my answer.