# How to use .Net MVC FileContenResult to return a image by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I built a website using `.net MVC`, and there is an `img` in the view. And the attribute `src` refer to an action `Render`, just like this:

```
<img src="XXX/render?..." />
public ActionResult Render()
{
   return new FileContentResult(byte[], "jpg"); // just like this
}
```

Thus, it works well and the "img" displays correctly. But now the url size is over limits. So I have to use `Post request` by ajax. And I use the `XMLHttpRequest` and assign the `responseXML` to the img's src . And it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try returning a Base64 encoded image

[Convert image path to base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-image-path-to-base64-string)

[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

I believe the problem you're encountering is that the XMLHttpRequest object only supports text responses and not binary

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest object only supports text responses and not binary" Not stricly true anymore, as [this Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Handling_binary_data) article explains.

Comment: This is true and I should have mentioned it. I generally disregard it because IE 9 doesn't support binary responses. This fact prevents most people from being able to take advantage of the feature