# How to convert Binary to byte[]? I received this: Cannot implicitly convert type ‘System.Data.Linq.Binary’ to ‘byte[]’

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

When I attempted to retrieve Binary (image from database)  to byte[] so I can display the image on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not adding as a comment, dont have enough reputation yet.

why not try store the image as a base-64 string instead of binary. Then you can use the string literal in the webpage directly

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,base64-string-from-database-here" />
```

If you want to convert an image to base-64 use the steps listed [here (Convert image to base64 using javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Or in C# you could use something similar to

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path))
{                 
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }                  
}
```

Courtesy of [@nitin-varpe - Convert Image to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-image-path-to-base64-string)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem is that I am not using javascript.

Comment: All I need is a mechanism to display an image from database to the webpage. The image is stored in database in binary format.

Comment: If you are adding the images to the databases manually one at a time you can use an online converter, i just provided a link as a potential solution to your problem.I added a code snippet of how you could potentially do it in C# - I'm just attempting a c# binary to base 64 conversion now

Comment: I managed to upload an image to the sql database and I can see it exists in binary format. How can I display that image back on the webpage. I am using WCF Framework, Linq, and I have create models for each page.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Binary binary = roomModel.RoomImage;
         byte[] bytes= binary.ToArray();

        string strBase64= Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
```