# How to convert TIFF to png/jpg in run time and display it in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, html, imageview, memorystream, asp.net-core-3.0

> I use Asp.Net Core 3.0 and I need to convert **TIFF string** to **png/jpg image** in **run time** and **display**
>   **it** but I phased this problem 
>  `ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, bool
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement, bool validateImageData)`

**First:** What I did,

1. I read the TIFF string from XML File as shown in the below code

[HttpGet]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ReadData()
{
   XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
   document.Load(@"Location In the Computer\MyFile.xml");
   XmlNodeList sign = document.GetElementsByTagName("sign");
   byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sign.Item(0).InnerText);
   ViewBag.Sign = ConvertTiffToImage(buffer); //This method convert tiff to png/jpg
   return View("Create");
}
```

2. I used **ConvertTiffToImage method** to convert tiff string to png/jpg image as shown in the below code

   ```
   private string ConvertTiffToImage(byte[] tiffBytes)
   {
       //Read the tiff and convert to png
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(tiffBytes);
       MemoryStream newMS = new MemoryStream();
       Bitmap.FromStream(ms).Save(newMS, ImageFormat.Png); //Error come here

       //Read the converted memorystream and insert it to string to display
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newMS);
       string pngImage = reader.ReadToEnd();
       return pngImage;
   }
   ```
3. I tried to display the Image using ViewBag as shown in the below code

```html
@if (ViewBag.Sign == null)
{
   <img src="~/Images/NoSignature.png" class="rounded" alt="No Signature Found for Emirates Id" />
}
else
{
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,@ViewBag.Sign" class="rounded" alt="Signature in Emirates Id" />
}
```

4. I debugged my application and the error raised in this point `Bitmap.FromStream(ms).Save(newMS, ImageFormat.Png);`, The displayed error is `ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, bool
   useEmbeddedColorManagement, bool validateImageData)`

**Second:** What I need to do is reading tiff string from XML file and display the image (png/jpg) using Viewbag in the run time.

**This is the XML file data:** `<sign>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</sign>`

**Third:** This is some resources that I search:
1. [Converting TIFF files to PNG in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566188/converting-tiff-files-to-png-in-net) 
2. [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp) 
3. [ASP.NET Core MVC, Get file from database, and render as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956254/asp-net-core-mvc-get-file-from-database-and-render-as-image)

> How to convert tiff to png/jpg and display it in the application run time in Asp.Net Core 3.0?