# error resolving System.ArgumentException using wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to convert Image to Base64String format,For that I am using this code

```
string conversionData = imageToBase64("http//localhost/MyService/Images/myImage.png");
```

the code of "imageToBase64()" is

```
private string imageToBase64(string path)
{
  using(Image image = Image.FromFile(path))
  {
   using(MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
   {
    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
   }
  }
 }
```

When I am passing path to this method I am getting the error "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occered ...".
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

take a look :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-image-path-to-base64-string.You missed image.Save(m, image.RawFormat)
Hope it will help

Comment: I am getting  ArgumentException at "Image.FromFile(path)"

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of fromfile cannot be URI, otherwise an error will be reported.

[image]

The interface that accesses WCF will return stream. We need to use the Httpwebrequest request interface to receive its stream,then save it locally before using fromfile.Here is a Demo:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8000/Service/GetImage?width=50&height=40");
            request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (File.Exists("d:\\name.png"))
                File.Delete("d:\\name.png");
            Stream outStream = System.IO.File.Create("d:\\name.png");
            Stream inStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            int l;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            do
            {
                l = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (l > 0)
                    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, l);
            }
            while (l > 0);
            outStream.Close();
            inStream.Close();

           Image image = Image.FromFile("d:\\name.png");
```