# How can I add image in JSON array

Tags: json

please how can I add image to this question. it is written in JSON array.
{
"question": "Nigeria National flag color is?",
"choice1": "Red Black and Gold",
"choice2": "Yellow Gold and Yellow",
"choice3": "Purple Red and Pink",
"choice4": "Green White and Green",
"answer": 4
}

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the image to byte array then add that byte as a JSON value in a JSON key.

example.

Image  -> byte array

JSON

```
{
  //... rest of the keys and value 
  "image": "byte array here"  
}
```

**NOTE:**

**1. if your images are of large size i.e. more than 1MB then use object host(AWS service or other cloud services).**

**2. Only use the above solution for less than 500KB images.**

Answer (score 0):

**1.You can base64 image encoding use to it.**

https://www.base64encode.org/

```
{ "question": "Nigeria National flag color is?", "choice1": "Red Black and Gold", "choice2": "Yellow Gold and Yellow", "choice3": "Purple Red and Pink", "choice4": "Green White and Green", "answer": 4 , "image": "base6encodeing" }
```

In  javascript:
[Convert image from url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-from-url-to-base64)

In c# [Convert an image (selected by path) to base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325661/convert-an-image-selected-by-path-to-base64-string)

**2. Image url use  in json.**

```
{ "question": "Nigeria National flag color is?", "choice1": "Red Black and Gold", "choice2": "Yellow Gold and Yellow", "choice3": "Purple Red and Pink", "choice4": "Green White and Green", "answer": 4 , "image": "http:\\mydomain.com\img\upload.jpeg" }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two option for adding image in the JSON :

1. You can upload your image to the server and get a server link for image, add path to the `JSON` and then you can show your image to the corresponding view.
2. You can get directory path for a particular image and add path to the `JSON`

in both ways `JSON` will look like this :

```
{
  "question": "https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff",
  "choice1": "Red Black and Gold",
  "choice2": "Yellow Gold and Yellow",
  "choice3": "Purple Red and Pink",
  "choice4": "Green White and Green",
  "answer": 4
}
```